# Android compose when updating data in the Room database, recomposition does not occur

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to update the data in the database and display the updated data on the screen.But I can't do it. The update occurs only after restarting the application.
What am I doing wrong?. Help please

```
fun list(model: MyViewModel = viewModel()) {

val list = model.listToDo.observeAsState(listOf()).value
val grouped = list.groupBy { it.isFinished }

LazyColumn(contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 8.dp)
    , verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    , ){
    grouped.forEach { (initial, contactsForInitial) ->
        stickyHeader {
            Text(
                "Section $initial",
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(8.dp)
            )
        }

        items(contactsForInitial) { contact     ->
            card(contact, model = model)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Function in viewmodel

```
fun update(task: ToDo){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.update(task)
    }
}
```

Function in the dao

```
 @Update
fun update(task: ToDo)
```

ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val repository = Repository.get()
val listToDo = repository.getListToDo()


fun delete(task: ToDo){
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       repository.delete(task)
   }
}

fun insertToDo(task: ToDo){
    repository.insertToDo(task = task)
}


fun update(task: ToDo){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.update(task)
    }
}}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole ViewModel? I can't see how the `model.listToDo` is wired up

Comment: @Jakoss Done. I added

Comment: The repository contains functions for accessing the DAO

Comment: And what does `getListToDo` return?

Comment: Oh wait, i see the error now. Will post the answer shorty

Comment: @Jakoss getListTodo returns LiveData<List<ToDo>. Well, that's the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not observing the state. I think this code:
`val list = model.listToDo.observeAsState(listOf()).value` just takes a single snapshot of the flow. Try it like that:
`val list by model.listToDo.observeAsState(listOf())`